# Querying BAccount, but BQL is querying for Vendor table instead of BAccount

Tags: acumatica

I have a BQL query that joined BAccount table, but when I view SQL Profiler, it is querying the Vendor table instead, which the object I'm trying to retrieve is not a vendor. This is for a custom selector that I am adding for a customer field in the SOLine table. All fields and tables used are base Acumatica fields and tables. Here is my BQL code:

```
[PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Specification")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<UploadFileRevision.comment, 
    InnerJoin<UploadFile, On<UploadFile.fileID, Equal<UploadFileRevision.fileID>>,
    InnerJoin<NoteDoc, On<NoteDoc.fileID, Equal<UploadFile.fileID>>,
    InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.noteID, Equal<NoteDoc.noteID>>,
    InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>
    >>>>, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>,
    Aggregate<GroupBy<UploadFileRevision.comment>>>),
typeof(UploadFileRevision.comment), typeof(UploadFile.name), 
typeof(UploadFile.fileID))]
```

The code translates to this in the SQL Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (12) MAX([UploadFileRevision].[FileID]), 
MAX([UploadFileRevision].[FileRevisionID]), NULL, MAX([UploadFileRevision].
[BlobHandler]), [UploadFileRevision].[Comment], 
MAX([UploadFileRevision].[Size]), MAX([UploadFileRevision].[OriginalName]), 
MAX([UploadFileRevision].[OriginalTimestamp]), MAX([UploadFileRevision].
[CreatedByID]), MAX([UploadFileRevision].[CreatedDateTime]), 
MAX([UploadFile].[FileID]), MAX([UploadFile].[Name]), MAX([UploadFile].
[CheckedOutComment]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([UploadFile].[Versioned]+0)), 
MAX([UploadFile].[CreatedByID]), MAX([UploadFile].[CreatedDateTime]), 
MAX([UploadFile].[LastRevisionID]), MAX([UploadFile].[CheckedOutBy]), 
MAX([UploadFile].[PrimaryPageID]), MAX([UploadFile].[PrimaryScreenID]), 
MAX([UploadFile].[tstamp]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([UploadFile].[IsHidden]+0)), 
CONVERT (BIT, MAX([UploadFile].[Synchronizable]+0)), MAX([UploadFile].
[SourceType]), MAX([UploadFile].[SourceUri]), MAX([UploadFile].
[SourceLogin]), MAX([UploadFile].[SourcePassword]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([UploadFile].[SourceIsFolder]+0)), MAX([UploadFile].[SourceMask]), 
MAX([UploadFile].[SourceNamingFormat]), MAX([UploadFile].
[SourceLastImportDate]), MAX([UploadFile].[SourceLastExportDate]), CONVERT 
(BIT, 
MAX([UploadFile].[IsPublic]+0)), MAX([UploadFile].[NoteID]), NULL, NULL, 
NULL, MAX([NoteDoc].[NoteID]), MAX([NoteDoc].[FileID]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[BAccountID]), NULL, MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[AcctReferenceNbr]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[ParentBAccountID]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[ConsolidateToParent]+0)), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[ConsolidatingBAccountID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[DefAddressID]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[DefContactID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[DefLocationID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[TaxRegistrationID]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[WorkgroupID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[tstamp]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[CreatedByID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[CreatedByScreenID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[CreatedDateTime]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[LastModifiedByID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[LastModifiedByScreenID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[LastModifiedDateTime]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[AcctCD]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[AcctName]), 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[Type]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[VendorClassID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TermsID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[DefPOAddressID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[CuryID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[CuryRateTypeID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PriceListCuryID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[DefaultUOM]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[AllowOverrideCury]+0)), 
CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[AllowOverrideRate]+0)), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[DiscTakenAcctID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[DiscTakenSubID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PrepaymentAcctID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PrepaymentSubID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[POAccrualAcctID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[POAccrualSubID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PrebookAcctID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[PrebookSubID]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PayToParent]+0)), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[BaseRemitContactID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].
[TaxZoneID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[Status]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[Vendor1099]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[Box1099]), 
CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[FATCA]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxAgency]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[UpdClosedTaxPeriods]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxReportPrecision]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxReportRounding]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxUseVendorCurPrecision]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxReportFinPeriod]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[TaxPeriodType]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[EnableTaxStartDate]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxYearStartDate]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[SalesTaxAcctID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[SalesTaxSubID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PurchTaxAcctID]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[PurchTaxSubID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[TaxExpenseAcctID]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[TaxExpenseSubID]), NULL, 
MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[OwnerID]), MAX([BAccount_BAccount].[NoteID]), NULL, 
NULL, NULL, CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[LandedCostVendor]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[IsLaborUnion]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[LineDiscountTarget]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[IgnoreConfiguredDiscounts]+0)), CONVERT 
(BIT, MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[ForeignEntity]+0)), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[LocaleName]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[SVATReversalMethod]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[SVATInputTaxEntryRefNbr]), 
MAX([BAccount_Vendor].[SVATOutputTaxEntryRefNbr]), MAX([BAccount_Vendor].
[SVATTaxInvoiceNumberingID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[BAccountID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[AcctReferenceNbr]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[ParentBAccountID]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[ConsolidateToParent]+0)), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[ConsolidatingBAccountID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[DefAddressID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[DefContactID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[DefLocationID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[TaxRegistrationID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[WorkgroupID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[OwnerID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[tstamp]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[CreatedByID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[CreatedByScreenID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[CreatedDateTime]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[LastModifiedByID]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[LastModifiedByScreenID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[LastModifiedDateTime]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[AcctCD]), 
MAX([Customer_BAccount].[Type]), NULL, CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[ConsolidateStatements]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[SharedCreditPolicy]+0)), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[StatementCustomerID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[SharedCreditCustomerID]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[CustomerClassID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[LanguageID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[DefSOAddressID]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[DefBillAddressID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[DefBillContactID]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[BaseBillContactID]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[TaxZoneID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[TermsID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[CuryID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[CuryRateTypeID]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[AllowOverrideCury]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[AllowOverrideRate]+0)), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[DiscTakenAcctID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[DiscTakenSubID]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[PrepaymentAcctID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[PrepaymentSubID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[COGSAcctID]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[COGSSubID]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[AutoApplyPayments]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[PrintStatements]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[PrintCuryStatements]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[SendStatementByEmail]+0)), MAX([Customer_Customer].[CreditRule]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[CreditLimit]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[CreditDaysPastDue]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[StatementType]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[StatementCycleId]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[StatementLastDate]), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[SmallBalanceAllow]+0)), MAX([Customer_Customer].[SmallBalanceLimit]), 
CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].[FinChargeApply]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[PayToParent]+0)), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[Status]), MAX([Customer_BAccount].[AcctName]), NULL, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[DefPaymentMethodID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].
[CCProcessingID]), MAX([Customer_Customer].[DefPMInstanceID]), CONVERT (BIT, 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[PrintInvoices]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, 
 MAX([Customer_Customer].[MailInvoices]+0)), MAX([Customer_BAccount].
[NoteID]), NULL, NULL, NULL, CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[PrintDunningLetters]+0)), CONVERT (BIT, MAX([Customer_Customer].
[MailDunningLetters]+0)), MAX([Customer_Customer].[LocaleName]), 
MAX([Customer_Customer].[UsrCertType])
FROM [UploadFileRevision] [UploadFileRevision]
INNER JOIN [UploadFile] [UploadFile] ON [UploadFile].CompanyID IN (1, 3) AND 
32 = SUBSTRING([UploadFile].CompanyMask, 1, 1) & 32 AND [UploadFile].
[FileID] = [UploadFileRevision].[FileID]
INNER JOIN [NoteDoc] [NoteDoc] ON [NoteDoc].CompanyID IN (1, 3) AND 32 = 
SUBSTRING([NoteDoc].CompanyMask, 1, 1) & 32 AND [NoteDoc].[FileID] = 
[UploadFile].[FileID]
INNER JOIN (
[Vendor] BAccount_Vendor
INNER JOIN [BAccount] BAccount_BAccount ON [BAccount_BAccount].CompanyID = 3 
AND [BAccount_BAccount].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0
) ON [BAccount_BAccount].[NoteID] = [NoteDoc].[NoteID] AND 
[BAccount_Vendor].CompanyID = 3 AND [BAccount_Vendor].
[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND [BAccount_Vendor].[BAccountID] = 
[BAccount_BAccount].[BAccountID]
INNER JOIN (
[Customer] Customer_Customer
INNER JOIN [BAccount] Customer_BAccount ON [Customer_BAccount].CompanyID = 3 
AND [Customer_BAccount].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0
) ON [Customer_BAccount].[BAccountID] = [BAccount_BAccount].[BAccountID] AND 
[Customer_Customer].CompanyID = 3 AND [Customer_Customer].
[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND [Customer_Customer].[BAccountID] = 
[Customer_BAccount].[BAccountID]
WHERE [UploadFileRevision].CompanyID IN (1, 3) AND 32 = 
SUBSTRING([UploadFileRevision].CompanyMask, 1, 1) & 32 AND 
[Customer_BAccount].[BAccountID] = @P0
GROUP BY [UploadFileRevision].[Comment]
ORDER BY [UploadFileRevision].[Comment], MAX([UploadFileRevision].[FileID]), 
MAX([UploadFileRevision].[FileRevisionID]) OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) /* 
SO.30.10.00 */',N'@P0 int',@P0=8934
```

You can see that when it goes to join the BAccount, it instead uses [Vender] BAccount_Vendor, but my BQL code does not contain anything referring to vendor. I even added a redundant join to the customer table, but it did nothing. Did I miss something to force it to look at the BAccount table instead of Vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace BAccount with BAccountR or BAccount2. There must be a cache initialized for the Vendor DAC in the Caches collection of your BLC before the BAccount cache - this is what usually causes BQL translated into a SQL query for a different DB table.

To check in what order caches were initialized, in the Immediate Window inside VS you can execute `this.Caches` for a custom BLC or `Base.Caches` for a BLC extension. I'm pretty sure you will have the Vendor cache initialized before the BAccount.

Unfortunately, my attempt to reproduce error "The multi-part identifier "BAccount2.BAccountID" could not be bound" didn't succeed. Here is the custom SOLine field declaration, that I used on my end:

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
    public abstract class usrComment : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Specification")]
    [PXSelector(
        typeof(Search5<UploadFileRevision.comment,
            InnerJoin<UploadFile, 
                On<UploadFile.fileID, Equal<UploadFileRevision.fileID>>,
            InnerJoin<NoteDoc, 
                On<NoteDoc.fileID, Equal<UploadFile.fileID>>,
            InnerJoin<BAccountR, 
                On<BAccountR.noteID, Equal<NoteDoc.noteID>>>>>,
            Where<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>,
            Aggregate<GroupBy<UploadFileRevision.comment>>>),
    typeof(UploadFileRevision.comment), typeof(UploadFile.name),
    typeof(UploadFile.fileID))]
    public string UsrComment { get; set; }
}
```

And the lookup seems to work without any problems:
[image]

Did I miss anything or did something wrong?

Comment: I switched BAccount to BAccount2 and also removed Customer. I also switched the Where clause to Where<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>. I'm getting the following error: The multi-part identifier "BAccount2.BAccountID" could not be bound. I also got that same error with BAccountR.

Comment: Also I ran Base.Caches in the Immediate Window and you were correct. Vendor is loaded before BAccount, and BAccount is loaded with a relation to Vendor it looks like:     [10]: {[PX.Objects.AP.Vendor, PXCache<PX.Objects.AP.Vendor>(0)]}
    [11]: {[PX.Objects.CR.BAccount, PXCache<PX.Objects.AP.Vendor>(0)]}

Comment: Sorry Ruslan, that was my fault. I noticed what I did. I didn't change one of the BAccounts to BAccountR. That was my fault. It works now! Thanks!

Comment: No worries, Eric. Glad to hear the issue got resolved!